# how to get the particular value from Json?

Tags: ios, swift3

I am having the Json data as shown below in this I need to get the data that which key value pair for default is 1 then i need to get the remaining dictionaries data and need to be passed to the user to display can any one tell me how to implement this ?

And my code is as shown below

```
            if let addressArray = jsonObj!.value(forKey: "address") as? NSArray{
                    for array in addressArray {
                        if let addressDict = array as? NSDictionary{
                            if let Default = addressDict.value(forKey: "default"){

                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
 "address": [
    {
      "default": 0, 
      "number": 9123456711, 
      "name": "Ramesh", 
      "address": "No:11/111 ,cross street,Nungambakkam,mylapore,chennai :600088"
    }, 
    {
      "default": 1, 
      "number": 8123456722, 
      "name": "Vignesh", 
      "address": "No:22/222 ,cross street,Perambur,chennai :600012"
    }, 
    {
      "default": 0, 
      "number": 7123456733, 
      "name": "Rajesh", 
      "address": "No:33/333 ,cross street,Villivakkam,chennai :600045"
    }
  ]
```

Comment: you finished almost what is your error?just add addressDict  into one array which satisfy the condition default is 1.then use that array to display

Comment: i need to get the data which key value pair default is one then that data needs to be displayed @DSDharma

Comment: that 's only how i am asking @DSDharma

Comment: it's not too hard even simple for beginner also just find & do it.gud luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check if Default equals 1 and add those values to an array.

```
var defaultArray = [NSDictionary]()
if let addressArray = jsonObj!.value(forKey: "address") as? NSArray{
                    for array in addressArray {
                        if let addressDict = array as? NSDictionary{
                            if let Default = addressDict.value(forKey: "default"){
                               if Default == 1 {
                               defaultArray.append(addressDict)
                              }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Step1: Prepare your model as shown in below code snippet.

```
class Addresses: NSObject {

var default = 0
var number = 0
var name = String()
var address = String()

init?(dictionary:[String:Any]) {

    guard let default = dictionary["default"],
        let number = dictionary["number"],
        let name = dictionary["name"],
        let address = dictionary["address"]
        else {
        return nil
    }
    self.default = default
    self.number = number
    self.name = name
    self.address = address
  }
 }
```

Step2: Declare an array to store parsed addresses.

```
var addressesArray = [Addresses]()
```

Step3:

```
if let addressArray = jsonObj!.value(forKey: "address") as? NSArray{
                for array in addressArray {
                    if let addressDict = array as? NSDictionary{
                        if let defaultValue = addressDict.value(forKey: "default") as? Int{
                            if defaultValue == 1 {
                             if let address = Addresses(dictionary: addressDict) {
                                addressesArray.append(address)
                           }
                          }

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Thats it, take care of datatypes, and you can use addressesArray to display data.

Comment: {
        AmountPaid = 1200;
        CLASSNO = 1;
        "CLASS_ID" = 2021;
        DateOfReciept = "2017-06-08T00:00:00";
        Description = "[{\"des\":\"Admission\",\"Amount\":1200},{\"des\":\"Due\",\"Amount\":0}]";
        MasterID = E0017;}] what if we have this kind of JSON data

Comment: your data is not in a json format. Use (http://jsoneditoronline.org) online jsonfnrmatter to validate your json data

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45136583/display-nested-array-from-json-data-to-tableview-using-alamofire here's my link will you help me

Comment: Yeah sure @Bikesh Thakur.