# How to make model class for following JSON response in swift iOS

Tags: ios, json, swift

Hi i am beginner  for swift ios and my requirement is have to display Json response to table list i got response from web-services and response seems like below

MY requirement is how to map that model classes to Array and how to display them in tableList can some one help me please

### JsonResponse:-

```
[{
  "_id" : "5470def9e0c0be27780121d7",
  "imageUrl" : "https:\/\/s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com\/api-static\/clubs\/5470def9e0c0be27780121d7_180.png",
  "name" : "Mondo",
  "hasVip" : false,
  "location" : {
    "city" : "Madrid"
  }
}, {
  "_id" : "540b2ff281b30f3504a1c72f",
  "imageUrl" : "https:\/\/s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com\/api-static\/clubs\/540b2ff281b30f3504a1c72f_180.png",
  "name" : "Teatro Kapital",
  "hasVippler" : false,
  "location" : {
    "address" : "Atocha, 125",
    "city" : "Madrid"
  }
}, {
  "_id" : "540cd44581b30f3504a1c73b",
  "imageUrl" : "https:\/\/s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com\/api-static\/clubs\/540cd44581b30f3504a1c73b_180.png",
  "name" : "Charada",
  "hasVippler" : false,
  "location" : {
    "address" : "La Bola, 13",
    "city" : "Madrid"
  }
}]
```

### mapping:

### Club:-

```
class Club { 

    var id: String = ""
    var name: String = ""
    var imageUrl: String = ""
    var hasVip: Bool = false
    var desc: String = ""
    var location: [Location] = []

}
```

### Location:-

```
class Location {

    var country: String = ""
    var city: String = ""
    var address: String = ""
    var zip: String = ""
    var underground: [String] = []

}
```

### NSURlSession code:-

```
class BackGroundPostCall: NSObject {

    var delegate:PostProtocol?

    func callPostService(url:String,params:NSDictionary){

        print("url is===>\(url)")

        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string:url)!)

        let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
        request.HTTPMethod = "POST"

        //Note : Add the corresponding "Content-Type" and "Accept" header. In this example I had used the application/json.
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")

        request.HTTPBody = try! NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(params, options: [])

        let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request) { data, response, error in
            guard data != nil else {
                print("no data found: \(error)")
                return
            }

            do {
                if let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: []) as? NSArray {
                    print("Response: \(json)")
                } else {
                    let jsonStr = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)// No error thrown, but not NSDictionary
                    print("Error could not parse JSON: \(jsonStr)")
                }
            } catch let parseError {
                print(parseError)// Log the error thrown by `JSONObjectWithData`
                let jsonStr = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
                print("Error could not parse JSON: '\(jsonStr)'")
            }
        }

        task.resume()
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to parse this json first and then save them in an array.

Comment: Looks fine, except `var location` is not an array in your JSON. If you want to easily map that you can use **ObjectMapper** library

Comment: can u please help me how can do that using ObjectMapper library i am new very new for swift

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44922697/how-to-get-the-particular-value-from-json/44923510#44923510. Check my answer and follow like that it is perfectly suitable for your requirement.

Comment: you can try this framework: https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON

Comment: Can you add your serialisation code.

Comment: i added please check

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41734982/parsing-nested-array-of-dictionaries-using-object-mapper/41735194#41735194

Comment: You can use https://www.json4swift.com to create model class and using this you will get the Response class and List class.

Answer (score 5):

For mapping you can use Alamofire's extension ObjectMapper.

Ex:

```
[{
"_id" : "5470def9e0c0be27780121d7",
"imageUrl" : "https:\/\/s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com\/api-static\/clubs\/5470def9e0c0be27780121d7_180.png",
"name" : "Mondo",
"hasVip" : false,
"location" : {
    "city" : "Madrid"
}
}, {
    "_id" : "540b2ff281b30f3504a1c72f",
    "imageUrl" : "https:\/\/s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com\/api-static\/clubs\/540b2ff281b30f3504a1c72f_180.png",
    "name" : "Teatro Kapital",
    "hasVippler" : false,
    "location" : {
        "address" : "Atocha, 125",
        "city" : "Madrid"
    }
}, {
    "_id" : "540cd44581b30f3504a1c73b",
    "imageUrl" : "https:\/\/s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com\/api-static\/clubs\/540cd44581b30f3504a1c73b_180.png",
    "name" : "Charada",
    "hasVippler" : false,
    "location" : {
        "address" : "La Bola, 13",
        "city" : "Madrid"
    }
}]
```

And mapper class:

```
import ObjectMapper

class Location: Mappable {
    var address: String?
    var city: String?

    required init?(map: Map){

    }

    func mapping(map: Map) {
        address <- map["address"]
        city <- map["city"]
    }
}

class Club: Mappable {
    var id: String?
    var imageUrl: Int?
    var name: String?
    var hasVip: Bool = false
    var location: Location?

    required init?(map: Map){

    }

    func mapping(map: Map) {
        id <- map["_id"]
        imageUrl <- map["imageUrl"]
        name <- map["name"]
        hasVip <- map["hasVippler"]
        location <- map["location"]
    }
}
```

And this way very flexible and transparent to use.

https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire
https://github.com/tristanhimmelman/AlamofireObjectMapper

Using example:

```
Alamofire.request(URL).responseArray { (response: DataResponse<[Club]>) in

    let clubs = response.result.value

    if let clubs = clubs {
        for club in clubs {
            print(club.name)
            print(club.location.city)           
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: how can i add that WeatherResponse to Array can you please add that code?

Comment: `let weatherResponseObject = WeatherResponse(JSONString: JSONString)`

Comment: I've added example of usage

Comment: Hi Zaak i am using NSURlSeesion for integrating with webservices and got result in the form of JSon Object like my response

Comment: then why this line again Alamofire.request(URL).responseArray { (response: DataResponse<[Club]>) in

Comment: i got response like above then how to parse response in the form of arrayList that's what i am asking

Comment: If you don't want to use frameworks like Alamofire then you have to implement simple loop and map Dictionary that you got from json in objects.

Answer (score 5):

You can make model class using this url : http://www.jsoncafe.com/

open this link and put your json in JSON tab and select any  Code Template that is you want. and there is you can also add prefix class name and root class name if you want other wise it is optional. and last click on generate button, your json class is ready.!!

Comment: How to use generate Class in controller?

Answer (score 3):

Step1: Create your model like below.

```
class Club { 
        var id: String = ""
        var name: String = ""
        var imageUrl: String = ""
        var hasVip: Bool = false
        var desc: String = ""
        var location = Location()

        init?(dictionary:[String:Any],location: Location) {
            guard let id = dictionary["_id"],
                let name = dictionary["name"],
                let imageUrl = dictionary["imageUrl"],
                let hasVip = dictionary["hasVippler"]
            else {
                return nil
            }
     self.id = id
     self.name = name
     self.imageUrl = imageUrl
     self.hasVip = hasVip
     self.location = location
  }
 }
}
class Location {

    var country: String = ""
    var city: String = ""
    var address: String = ""
    var zip: String = ""

   init?(dictionary:[String:Any]) {
            guard let country = dictionary["country"],
                let city = dictionary["city"],
                let address = dictionary["address"],
                let zip = dictionary["zip"]
            else {
                return nil
            }
     self.country = country
     self.city = city
     self.address = address
     self.zip = zip
  }
 }
}
```

Step2: Declare your array as below.

```
var myTargetArray = [Club]()
```

Step3: Json Parsing.

```
    do {
            if let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: []) as? NSArray {
                print("Response: \(json)")

            for club in json {
                   if let clubDictionary = club as? NSDictionary { 
                     if let locationDict = clubDictionary["location"] as? NSDictionary{
                         if let location = Location(dictionary: locationDict) {

                           if let clubObj = Club(dictionary: clubDictionary, location:location) {
                            myTargetArray.append(clubObj)
                       }
                   }
                }
            }
        }
            } else {
                let jsonStr = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)// No error thrown, but not NSDictionary
                print("Error could not parse JSON: \(jsonStr)")
            }
        } catch let parseError {
            print(parseError)// Log the error thrown by `JSONObjectWithData`
            let jsonStr = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
            print("Error could not parse JSON: '\(jsonStr)'")
        }
```

Note: I removed underground array from location model since your json data does not contain it.
Finally you can use your target array as your tableview source. Happy coding...

Comment: If any datatype conflicts occurs just type cast them accordingly.

Comment: if let locationDict = club["location"] as? NSDictionary{ line showing errors

Answer (score 2):

Model class:

```
class test : Unboxable {
let id : String
let imageURl : String
let name : String
let hasVip : Bool
let city : String

required init(unboxer: Unboxer) throws {
    self.id = unboxer.unbox(key: "id") ?? ""
    self.imageURl = unboxer.unbox(key: "imageUrl") ?? ""
    self.name = unboxer.unbox(key: "name") ?? ""
    self.hasVip = unboxer.unbox(key: "hasVip") ?? false
    self.city = (unboxer.unbox(key: "city") ?? nil)!
}
}
```

parse json:

```
if let object = json as? [Any] {
                // json is an array

                var data :[test] = []
                for respObject in object {

                    var dict = respObject as? Dictionary<String,AnyObject>
                    dict?["city"] = dict?["location"]?["city"] as AnyObject
                     let result1: [test] = try unbox(dictionaries: [dict!])
                    data.append(contentsOf: result1)

                }

                print(data)
```

For more details follow 
https://github.com/JohnSundell/Unbox

Answer (score 0):

**Api call with model class, swiftyjson and alamofire,Pod install alamofire and swiftyjson libraries, create collection view cell class, Create a class and write the following code
**

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire
import SwiftyJSON
var myResponse : JSON? = nil
var users : [reasonList] = []
class HomeViewController: UIViewController {
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
 feedbackApi()
}

func feedbackApi(){
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        let url = URL(string: "--------")
        let urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url!)
        Alamofire.request(urlRequest)
            .responseJSON { response in
                switch response.result{
                case.success(let data):
                    print("dddd :",data)
                    self.myResponse = JSON(data)
                    print(self.myResponse as Any)
                    let a = self.myResponse![0]["reasonList"]
                    print(a)
                    for i in 0..<a.count{
                        let single = reasonList(reasonListJson: a[i])
                        self.users.append(single)

                    }
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.tableView.reloadData()
                    }
                case .failure(let error):
                    print("dddd",error)
                }  
        }
    }
}
```

}

**create a model class**

```
import Foundation
import SwiftyJSON

class user{
var deviceId = String()
var deviceName = String()
var deviceLocationId = Int()
var locationName = String()
var welcomeText = String()
var reason=[reasonList]()
init(userJson:JSON)  {
    self.deviceId = userJson["deviceId"].stringValue
     self.deviceName = userJson["deviceName"].stringValue
     self.deviceLocationId = userJson["deviceLocationId"].intValue
     self.locationName = userJson["locationName"].stringValue
     self.welcomeText = userJson["welcomeText"].stringValue
    self.reason = [reasonList(reasonListJson: userJson["reason"])]
}}
class reasonList{
var reason = String()
var id = Int()
init(reasonListJson:JSON) {
    self.reason = reasonListJson["reason"].stringValue
    self.id = reasonListJson["id"].intValue
]}
```

**create a collection view in view **

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire
import SwiftyJSON
class ReasonViewController: UIViewController,UICollectionViewDelegate,UICollectionViewDataSource {
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    //DelayCall()


    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
func DelayCall() {
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2.0) { // Change `2.0` to the desired number of seconds.
        _ = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "HomeViewController")as! HomeViewController
        self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
    }
}
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return users.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "ReasonCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! ReasonCollectionViewCell
    let useee = users[indexPath.row]

    print(useee)
   cell.reasonLabel.text = useee.reason
    return cell
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make model class using this url : https://www.json4swift.com/

Open this link and paste your JSON and select from below option you want. Click generate, it will generate class files you can download and used it in your project.