# In the mentioned url i need to get only first dictionary from the url?

Tags: ios, swift3

In this order detail array i am having 10 dictionaries but i need to display only first dictionary can any one help me how to implement this ?

http://www.json-generator.com/api/json/get/bUKEESvnvS?indent=2

here is my code shown below

```
func downloadJsonWithURL() {
        let url = NSURL(string: self.url)
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: (url as URL?)!, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) -> Void in
            if let jsonObj = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as? NSDictionary {
               self.orderdetailsArray = (jsonObj!.value(forKey: "Orders detail") as? [[String: AnyObject]])!
                for array in self.orderdetailsArray {
                    let key = "OrderId"
                    let value = "#1000501"
                    for (key,value) in array{
                    if let addressDict = array as? NSDictionary{
                        if let orderid = addressDict.value(forKey: "OrderId"){
                            self.orderid.append(orderid as! String)
                        }
                        if let orderdate = addressDict.value(forKey: "OrderDate"){
                            self.orderdate.append(orderdate as! String)
                        }
                        if let subtotal = addressDict.value(forKey: "SubTotal"){
                            self.subTotal.append(subtotal as! Int)
                        }
                        if let Shipping = addressDict.value(forKey: "Shipping"){
                            self.shippingPrice.append(Shipping as! Int)
                        }
                        if let tax = addressDict.value(forKey: "Tax"){
                            self.tax.append(tax as! Int)
                        }
                        if let grandtotal = addressDict.value(forKey: "GrandTotal"){
                            self.grandTotal.append(grandtotal as! Int)
                        }
                        if let shippingAddress = addressDict.value(forKey: "ShippingAddress"){
                            self.shippingAddress.append(shippingAddress as AnyObject)
                        }
                        if let shippingMethod = addressDict.value(forKey: "ShippingMethod"){
                            self.shippingMethod.append(shippingMethod as AnyObject)
                        }
                        if let billingAddress = addressDict.value(forKey: "BillingAddress"){
                            self.billingAddress.append(billingAddress as AnyObject)
                        }
                        if let paymentMethod = addressDict.value(forKey: "PayMentMethod"){
                            self.paymentMethod.append(paymentMethod as AnyObject)
                        }
                        self.itemsArray = addressDict.value(forKey: "Items detail") as! [[String : AnyObject]]
                    }
                }
                }
                OperationQueue.main.addOperation({
                    self.tableDetails.reloadData()
                })
            }
        }).resume()
    }
```

Comment: basically you just need to get the first entry from the response right?

Comment: yes the first dictionary @Joshua

Comment: @VamsiKrishna Do mark my answer as useful as well if it solved your problem

Comment: yes bro @SamarthKejriwal

Comment: how to display **item details : ["ItemQty": 3**] have you done this

Comment: @BikeshThakur post in a question and i will help you with this

Comment: @SamarthKejriwal https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45136583/display-nested-array-from-json-data-to-tableview-using-alamofire help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this. :

```
let jsonObj = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as? NSDictionary

guard let Ordersdetail = jsonObj["Orders detail"] as? [NSDictionary] else {
        print("Cannot find key 'Orderdetails' in \(jsonObj)")
        return
    }
```

To access the contents of the first dictionary do this:

```
 var orderid = Ordersdetail[0]["OrderId"]!
 var shippingadress = Ordersdetail[0]["ShippingAddress"]!
 var total = Ordersdetail[0]["GrandTotal"]!
 var subtotal = Ordersdetail[0]["SubTotal"]!
 var tax = Ordersdetail[0]["Tax"]!
 var shipping = Ordersdetail[0]["Shipping"]!
```

Comment: You should not use `NSDictionary` in Swift, but use the native Swift alternative, `Dictionary`.

Comment: Yes that is acceptable .i forgot to correct it :) Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Hi if you want first dictionary of that

```
self.orderdetailsArray
```

then

```
if let firstDictInfo = self.orderdetailsArray.first as? [String:Any] {
 // Do your stuff here
 print(firstDictInfo["OrderId"])
}
```

Comment: in the first dictionary how i need to get the remaining key value pairs i.e is orderid ,orderdate etc

Answer (score 0):

Instead of looping through the whole dictionary is dictionaries, you should just take the first dictionary and only parse that. There was also quite a few other conceptual problems with your code. In Swift, don't use `NSDictionary`, but use the native Swift version, `Dictionary`, which keeps the type information of its contents. Also, use conditional casting to make sure your program doesn't crash even if the received data is wrong/unexpected and don't use force unwrapping of optionals.

Also, when parsing a JSON response in Swift, in general it is not necessary and not a good idea to iterate through the key-value pairs of the dictionaries in the response. You should know what data structure you expect, otherwise you can't parse it properly and since you can directly access dictionary values in Swift if you know the key it corresponds to, there's no need to iterate through the dictionary in a loop.

```
func downloadJsonWithURL() {
        let url = URL(string: self.url)
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) -> Void in
            if let jsonObj = (try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments)) as? [String:Any] {
               guard let self.orderdetailsArray =  jsonObj["Orders detail"] as? [[String: AnyObject]] else {return}
               guard let firstOrderDetails = self.orderdetailsArray.first else {return}
               let key = "OrderId"
               let value = "#1000501"
               if let ordered = firstOrderDetails["OrderId] as? String {
                   self.orderid.append(orderid)
               }
               if let orderdate = firstOrderDetails["OrderDate"] as? String{
                   self.orderdate.append(orderdate)
               }
               if let subtotal = firstOrderDetails["SubTotal"] as? Int{
                   self.subTotal.append(subtotal)
               }
               if let shipping = firstOrderDetails["Shipping"] as? Int{
                   self.shippingPrice.append(shipping)
               }
               if let tax = firstOrderDetails["Tax"] as? Int{
                  self.tax.append(tax)
               }
               if let grandtotal = firstOrderDetails["GrandTotal"] as? Int{
                  self.grandTotal.append(grandtotal)
               }
               if let shippingAddress = firstOrderDetails[ "ShippingAddress"] as? AnyObject{ //why don't you store it as a String?
                  self.shippingAddress.append(shippingAddress)
               }
               if let shippingMethod = firstOrderDetails[ "ShippingMethod"] as? AnyObject{
                  self.shippingMethod.append(shippingMethod)
               }
               if let billingAddress = firstOrderDetails[ "BillingAddress"] as? AnyObject {
                  self.billingAddress.append(billingAddress)
               }
               if let paymentMethod = firstOrderDetails ["PayMentMethod"] as? AnyObject{
                  self.paymentMethod.append(paymentMethod)
               }
               guard let itemDetails = firstOrderDetails["Items detail"] as? [[String : AnyObject]] else {return}
               self.itemsArray = itemDetails
                    }
                }
                }
                OperationQueue.main.addOperation({
                    self.tableDetails.reloadData()
                })
            }
        }).resume()
    }
```

I haven't compiled and run the code, so make sure you check for any typos/inconsistencies. Also, make sure you change the types of the objects you store are AnyObjects to specific types.